# MongoDB find with regex behaves differently from Java

Tags: java, regex, mongodb

Regex find with MongoDB 2.4.6 is not behaving the same way as the Java Pattern class does. Can anyone explain why?

Inserting data in MongoDB:

```
db.Project.insert({ "_id" : "e0b57d9e-744c-471e-ae95-22a389d2988d", "name" : "Project.20131106101344433" });
```

Finding all Projects:

```
db.Project.find()

{
    "_id" : "e0b57d9e-744c-471e-ae95-22a389d2988d",
    "name" : "Project.20131106101344433"
}
```

Finding all Projects whose name is "t":

```
db.Project.find({"name" : /t/})

{
    "_id" : "e0b57d9e-744c-471e-ae95-22a389d2988d",
    "name" : "Project.20131106101344433"
}
```

Checking that sole Project name does not match regex "t":

```
@Test
public void regex() {
    assertTrue(!Pattern.matches("t", "Project.20131106101344433"));
}
```

As you see, the regex db.Project.find returns a Project whose name is not "t", but does contain "t". What am I missing?

Thanks!

Comment: Why are you using regex instead of string literal if you want an exact match?

Comment: I agree, it's just to show that the /t/ expression matches anything that contains "t" when I expect it to behave differently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case `db.Project.find({"name" : /t/})` you are not looking for a document whose name is `t`, you are looking for every document whose name contains `t`. You can read about PECL  [here](http://www.comp.leeds.ac.uk/Perl/matching.html) and test what are you doing [here](http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/perl/index.html).

To find exact match you have to do `{"name" : 't'}`

Comment: I see, looks like I'm gonna have to learn a different syntax. Thanks!